# Angularjs oauth popup window, wait for JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I need to make an oauth request and I would like to start the request in a new window.

I know that I can open the window like this:

```
var authWindow = $window.open("/auth/google/signin", "");
```

My server will handle the callback and respond with JSON:

```
 app.get('/auth/google/signin',
    passport.authenticate('google', { scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'}),
    function(req, res, next) {
      // The request will be redirected to Google for authentication, so this
      // function will not be called.
    }
  );

app.get('/auth/google/callback',
    function(req, res, next) {
      passport.authenticate('google', function(err, user, info) {
        console.log('google authenticate callback');

        // do some stuff, then send back token and user...

        res.json({
          token:token,
          user: user
        });

      })(req, res, next);
    }
  );
```

I need to wait until the popup is redirected  to /auth/google/callback and the JSON data is returned from the server.

How do I wait for the redirect and the JSON response from the server?

Once I have waited and I have the JSON data what is the best way to give it back? Callback? postMessage()?

Comment: You can not open a 'hidden window'
instead create an iframe that is hidden & store the results in a cookie.

Comment: Sorry don't need hidden window as user will need to enter credentials. Shouldn't I however be able to get JSON data back from the child window once oath is complete without using cookies?

Comment: No, you need to transfer the data by using cookies. Most developers create a set of 3 or more MD5 hashed strings to match to a field in your database. Transfer the 3 hashes using cookies. You can take it a step further by adding SSL to the pages you are using for oAuth.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can.
Here is my solution: using JS and Nodejs as backend.
The main skills is: window.postMessage
The main flow is :
 1. Client ask signup page, server response.
 2. Signup page trigger oauth process, it would use "window.open("http://your_server/oauth_page")"
 3. the oauth_page do several things

```
   a. Check the state(default/success)   
   b. if in dedault state, using window.opener.postMessages('ready','*')  
      to tell main window(signup page) I am ready.
      Then signup page would listen messages and return which oauth url assigned.  
      Because I have several oauth methods in one page(Github/Google+/Facebook)  
   c. The oauth_page would send XHR request to server.  
   d. server would send redirect_url back to oauth_page.  
   e. oauth_page would use "window.location_url" to redirect. Now you can see the authorization page.  
   f.The authorization result would send back to server.  
   g.server would run exchange code, take access_token and get info you wanted.... I supposed you know this process.(passport library do.)  
   h.return the oauth_page to the same child window! The magic is that window.opener is still the signup page,so you can send result back as before.
```

4.The signup page would recieve the result!.

---

It looks quite long process but quite simple in code.
Here is my signup page code

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title= title
    body
        h1= title
        p Welcome to #{title}
        button(id="github-oauth" data-oauth-server-url="github") Sign up by Github
        button(id="google-oauth" data-oauth-server-url="google") Sign up by Google
        button(id="facebook-oauth" data-oauth-server-url="facebook") Sign up by Facebook
        script(type="text/javascript").
            window.onload = function() {
                var oauth_page;
                var oauth_server_url;
                function createOauthButtonListner(elem) {
                    elem.addEventListener("click", function () {
                        oauth_page = window.open("http://localhost:3000/oauth_page");
                        //determine which button is triggered.
                        oauth_server_url = elem.getAttribute("data-oauth-server-url");
                        console.log(oauth_server_url);
                    })
                };
                window.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
                    if (e.data == "ready") {
                        // send oauth url
                        oauth_page.postMessage(oauth_server_url, "http://localhost:3000");
                    } else {
                        // return oauth resut
                        console.log(e.data);
                    }
                }, false);
                createOauthButtonListner(document.getElementById("github-oauth"));
                createOauthButtonListner(document.getElementById("google-oauth"));
                createOauthButtonListner(document.getElementById("facebook-oauth"));
            }
```

Here is my Oauth_page

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title= "Oauth Page"
    body
        p Welcome to Oauth page
        p#status #{status}
        p#content #{content}
        script(type="text/javascript").
            window.onload = function(){
                // return msg to host window
                if (document.getElementById('status').innerHTML == 'success') {
                    window.opener.postMessage(document.getElementById('content').innerHTML, '*');
                    window.close();
                }else if(document.getElementById('status').innerHTML == 'default'){
                    window.opener.postMessage('ready', '*');
                }
                // redirect to oauth page
                window.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
                    console.log(window);
                    if (e.origin != "http://localhost:3000") {
                        console.log("error");
                        return;
                    } else {
                        if (document.getElementById('status').innerHTML == 'default') {
                            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            xhttp.open("GET", e.data, true);
                            xhttp.send();
                            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                                if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                                    window.location.href = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText).redirect_url;
                                }
                            };
                        }
                    }
                }, false);
            };
```

My server side code (quite messy :P)

```
router.get('/oauth_page', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('oauth', {status: 'default', content: 'none'});
})

// for github oauth
router.get('/github', function(req, res){
  var github_oauth_url = "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize" +
      "?client_id=" + github_client_id  +
      "&scope=user" ;
  res.send(JSON.stringify({"redirect_url":github_oauth_url}));
});

router.get('/github/callback', function(req, res){
    var code = req.query.code;
    var token_option = {
        url:"https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token",
        method:"POST",
        form:{
            code: code,
            client_id: github_client_id,
            client_secret: github_secret_id
        }
    };
  request(token_option, function(err, response, body){
      if(err){
          res.send(response);
      }
      var regex = /\=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\&([a-zA-Z])+\=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/;
      var result = body.match(regex);
      console.log(result, body);
      var token = result[1];

      var info_option = {
          url:"https://api.github.com/user",
          method:"GET",
          headers:{
              "User-Agent": "Awesome-Octocat-App",
              "Authorization":"token "+ token
          }
      }
      request(info_option, function(err, response, body){
         if(err){
             res.send(err);
         }
          res.render('oauth', {status: 'success', content:body});
      });
  });
});
```

In signup page, open the console you can see the result.
Feel free to ask me questions ;)
I worked for this in a week.
Hope it could help you.